# img onclick doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Trying to run the following:

JS:

```
  $('#my-modal').modal();
```

markup:

```
<img src="\Images\Browser\file_types\d8d74cae-2186-42ad-a932-3aa4b75e0f12.png" title="name: a3" onclick="Attachment_onClick(" bfa9ec7e-d781-4523-a4ee-dd587f699c18")="" "="">
```

but never gets to

```
function Attachment_onClick(attachment)
{
    $('#my-modal').modal('show');

}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many quotes - you can't use `"onClick=something("` - both with double quotes.

```
<img src="\Images\Browser\file_types\d8d74cae-2186-42ad-a932-3aa4b75e0f12.png" 
 title="name: a3" 
 onclick="Attachment_onClick('bfa9ec7e-d781-4523-a4ee-dd587f699c18')" />
```